# git HEAD detached and the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git

I can't push new commit to git

because my git lg is HEAD detached

and I don't know how to fix 
[image]

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have added new commits on top of the detached HEAD. If you haven't done that, you could probably just check out a branch, such as `git checkout master` (make sure you make a backup of your repository first). Can you clarify what you mean by not being able to push new commit to git, which commit would that be? Is it visible in your picture?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The 6c32913 is new push, the others branch need to direction 6c32913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `6c32913`, try

```
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
# or
git pull origin -r master
```

`6c32913` will be rebased onto `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself working in a detached HEAD state and you have made one or more commits which you want to keep long term, one easy fix is to just checkout a new branch from your current point:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

From here, you may do something like merge this new branch into its intended target.

Comment: What is `6c32913` here?

Comment: in the picture, it is new commit on second line